# My AC condenser is running when I turn heat on and it is not a heat pump, any advice?

Tags: hvac, heating

I am wondering why the AC unit would be running and blowing warm air outside when heat is on.

Comment: This looks like it's going to need some more detail...  What does "blowing my warm air outside" mean?  A house HVAC unit typically doesn't move air from inside to outside.  Have you done anything to the thermostat recently?

Answer (score 1):

You clearly have a problem with the controls of your heating and cooling system.  If he outdoor unit is straight cooling and is running when you are calling for heat, something is wrong. This is a fairly technical problem, I recommend you consult a pro.  You may have a bad thermostat.  But in any event this is costing you unnecessarily in energy cost and could damage the components of your system. Good Luck!